# How to specify constraints/restrictions on $x$ in $\forall x$? For example, for all $x$ where $1 \leq x \leq n$, we have $S(x)$.

Tags: logic, notation, first-order-logic

For example, if want to make a statement $S(x)$ about all $x$ in $[1, n]$, how would I write that using $\forall$?

- $\forall x : 1 \leq x \leq n : S(x)$?
- $\forall x \in [1, n] : S(x)$?
- $\forall (1 \leq x \leq n) : S(x)$?

In this case, $x$ is an index, so it's is an integer. This is implied, but how would one state that explicitly?

- $\forall x : 1 \leq x \leq n, x \in \mathbb N : S(x)$?
- $\forall x \in [1, n] \subset \mathbb N : S(x)$?
- $\forall (1 \leq x \leq n, x \in \mathbb N) : S(x)$?

They're not very readable.

Comment: Most of the time, clear natural language is preferable to symbolic logic. So "for all integers $x\in [1,n]$, we have $S(x)$" would be fine. If you really want to avoid words, which again I don't recommend, my personal preference would be $$\forall x\in\mathbb{N}(1\le x\le n\implies S(x)).$$ (The idea is that the restriction to naturals is "more fundamental" than the restriction to $[1,n]$.)